# Error when download a file from server using scp

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, scp

I wanna to download some files and directory from server using `scp`.

```
scp -p 3031 root@serverIP -D 1080:/dir_path/. /local_path/
```

But with this command I get some error:

> cp: cannot stat '3031': No such file or directory
>
> cp: cannot stat 'root@serverIP': No such file or directory
>
> cp: cannot stat '-D': No such file or directory
>
> ssh: connect to host 1080 port 22: Invalid argument

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switches have their meaning and their order matters. The correct path (assuming you want to download a `file`) would be:

```
scp -P 3031 root@serverIP:/dir_path/file /local_path/
```

Synopsis in the manual page for `scp` should be your friend:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> `scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`

Answer (score 1):

Port argument should be passed with -P not -p

Try this

```
scp -p root@serverIP:/dir_path/ /local_path/ -P 3031
```

-p is for preserving modification and access times and modes of the original file

If you got the ssh key then try this

```
scp -i path/to/file.pem -p root@serverIP:/dir_path/ /local_path/ -P 3031
```